# Is it possible to modify the arrow that collapses the sidebar?

Tags: css, r, shiny, bslib

I'd like to move the little arrow that toggles the sidebar up to the top or basically just make it more visible/easier to close.

[image: Example dashboard]

```
  library(bslib)
  library(shiny)
  library(ggplot2)
  
  ui <- page_sidebar(
    title = "Example dashboard",
    sidebar = sidebar(
      varSelectInput("var", "Select variable", mtcars)
    ),
    card(
      full_screen = TRUE,
      card_header("My plot"),
      plotOutput("p")
    )
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$p <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(mtcars) + geom_histogram(aes(!!input$var))
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can shift the arrow to the top and also apply many more styling options using `css`. The container where the arrow is located in can be accessed by `.bslib-sidebar-layout > .collapse-toggle` and if you want to modify the icon itself you can add a `> .collapse-icon` afterwards. Here is one example. Including

```
.bslib-sidebar-layout > .collapse-toggle {
    padding: 100px 0;
    margin-bottom: 350px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
        
.bslib-sidebar-layout > .collapse-toggle > .collapse-icon {
    fill: red !important;
}
```

yields:

- a vertical larger container (`padding`),
- the container shifted more towards the top (`margin-bottom`),
- a yellow color of the container (`background-color`),
- a red color of the arrow (`fill`).

[image]

```
library(bslib)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


ui <- page_sidebar(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML(
        "
        .bslib-sidebar-layout > .collapse-toggle {
            padding: 100px 0;
            margin-bottom: 350px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        
        .bslib-sidebar-layout > .collapse-toggle > .collapse-icon {
            fill: red !important;
        }        
        "
    ))),
    title = "Example dashboard",
    sidebar = sidebar(
        varSelectInput("var", "Select variable", mtcars)
    ),
    card(
        full_screen = TRUE,
        card_header("My plot"),
        plotOutput("p")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$p <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(mtcars) + geom_histogram(aes(!!input$var))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice answer by @Jan, as usual. Here is another possible answer. You can modify the function `bslib:::collapse_icon`.

```r
# bslib:::collapse_icon
function () 
{
  if (!is_installed("bsicons")) {
    icon <- "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 16 16\" class=\"bi bi-chevron-down collapse-icon\" style=\"fill:currentColor;\" aria-hidden=\"true\" role=\"img\" ><path fill-rule=\"evenodd\" d=\"M1.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 10.293l5.646-5.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z\"></path></svg>"
    return(HTML(icon))
  }
  bsicons::bs_icon("chevron-down", class = "collapse-icon", 
                   size = NULL)
}
```

So, either you modify the SVG path, or you install the **bsicons** package and you change the [Bootstrap icon](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/). Since the function is not exported, you can modify it with `assignInNamespace`. Here I adopt the second way and I replace the `chevron-down` icon with the `chevron-double-down` icon, which is a bit more visible.

```r
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(ggplot2)

assignInNamespace(
  "collapse_icon", 
  function() {
    bsicons::bs_icon(
      "chevron-double-down", class = "collapse-icon", size = NULL
    ) 
  },
  ns = "bslib"
)

ui <- page_sidebar(
  title = "Example dashboard",
  sidebar = sidebar(
    varSelectInput("var", "Select variable", mtcars)
  ),
  card(
    full_screen = TRUE,
    card_header("My plot"),
    plotOutput("p")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$p <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars) + geom_histogram(aes(!!input$var))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Maybe there's a better Bootstrap icon. Otherwise use the other way: find a nice SVG icon (e.g. a filled triangle) and copy its code.

[image]